# 2 (or 3 or 4...) websites in IIS, pointing to same ASP.NET application IIS

Tags: iis

I wish to maintain a single a single code base (ASP.NET app) setup at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApp, and point several IIS websites at this single code base.

Will this be an issue? Will IIS see this as a conflict in resource allocation?

Reasons why I want to do it:

- Each IIS website can then have it's own IP, SSL cert, etc.
- Each IIS website can have it's own ISAPI filters installed for friendly URLs, etc.
- Easier to maintain the code base by having single point of deployment

Answer (score 0):

From a sysadmin perspective, this is perfectly fine, and you can add multiple host headers to IIS so that it supports multiple IP addresses and domain names on the same website.

It would be up to your application to handle friendly URL's etc. based on the domain name... but that's a question for stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Binding-wise you have both IPs and host header bindings. I would have to warn about individualized configuration. Relying on the local web.config files will cause all sites to share the same configuration. You would have to rely on configuration based on location elements.

```
<location path="Site1">
<!-- Site 1 individual config -->
</location>
<location path="Site2">
<!-- Site 2 individual config -->
</location>
```

Of course, configuration that will be shared amongst all of the sites can be done via local web.config files or by inheritance.